# How do I fetch the values from the xml using xmlstarlet in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, xmlstarlet

The XML file is as below : test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<metadata>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <key><![CDATA[bip:DisplayName]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[MY_Test_Free_Quantity_DM]]></value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key><![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[undefined]]></value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key><![CDATA[propertyMap]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key><![CDATA[path]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[%2FCustom%2FOpen+Quantity+Report%2FData+Models%2FMY_Test_Free_Quantity_DM.xdo]]></value>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</metadata>
```

Need to extract "%2FCustom%2FOpen+Quantity+Report%2FData+Models%2FMY_Test_Free_Quantity_DM.xdo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/metadata/entries/entry[key='path']" -v value your.xml
%2FCustom%2FOpen+Quantity+Report%2FData+Models%2FMY_Test_Free_Quantity_DM.xdo
```